# How to interpret the split plot anova result? Please explain to me about split plot anova

Tags: anova, split-plot

I'am analyzing an artcle , it said that split plot anova was conducted to asses the impact of two different interventions on student scores on achievement test, across two time period (pre intervention, post intervention)[image]

Please help me to interpret the tabel result

Comment: I was actually attach the picture :(

Comment: where is Table 3. Also, explain two interventions ?